# How do I change icon dynamically condition based which is being displayed via typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, command-line-interface

I am displaying icons via typescript using material icon's name. I want to change the icon according to the condition.
Say like in typescript the name of icon is 'power_off',
`if power is false then we want to use 'power_off' but if the power is true then we want to use 'power'`.
I am using another component for such code but it is connected with that component and the name is getting changed in this component but in the view it is not getting changed.
Please help me out with this.
Thank you in advance.

```
{name: 'associateDriver', visible: true, tooltip: 'Associate Driver', icon: 'person', type: 'icon'},
                {name: 'associateServiceReminder', visible: true, tooltip: 'Service Reminder', icon: 'add_alert', type: 'icon'},
                {name: 'busStopStatus', visible: false, tooltip: 'Bus Stop Status', icon: 'pin_drop', type: 'icon'},
                {name: 'delete', visible: false, tooltip: 'Delete', icon: 'delete', type: 'icon'},
                {name: 'immobilize', visible: true, tooltip: 'Immobilize', icon: 'power_off', type: 'icon'}
```

Comment: please share the what you done so far!

Comment: Please show your code instead of a description of your code.

Comment: Next time provide a code. for both .html and .ts

Answer (score 2):

I hope this help

```
<div> 
  <mat-icon *ngIf="power">power_on<mat-icon>
  <mat-icon *ngIf="!power">power_off<mat-icon>
</div>
```

Comment: I think the problem is `the name is getting changed in this component but in the view it is not getting changed`. Not sure this will help, we cannot tell until OP shows their code.

Comment: Show us your code, I can't imagine how your code looks like.

Comment: This is only your data source, not your code. Also, please edit your original question, don't add this below in a comment.

Comment: Jeremy Thille You are right its not getting changed in view thats what I want to do...Please suggest if you can help.

Answer (score 1):

Can also try this; a compact version

`<mat-icon>{{power ? 'power_on' : 'power_off' }}<mat-icon>`